# Cython modifiy pointer from c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pointers, cython

I need to modify my NumPy arrays which I am passing from cython to c++ function. Everything works fine but when I print out the value after calling the c++ modifier function, the value remains the same as it was before calling the function. I also tried the same with string but it does not work out as well. I used the typed memoryviews to access the memory. Below is the code (keeping only relevant stuff related to this question) that I used

**test.h**

```
#include <iostream>

struct S1 {
    float* buffer;
    int length;
};

int modify(S1* s1, char* str);
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test_modify.h"

int modify(S1* s1, char* str) {
    str = "newstr"; // string modify

    int out_idx = 0;


    while(out_idx < s1->length) {
        s1->buffer[out_idx++] = 10; // array modify
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**test.pyx**

```
from numpy import pi, cos, sin, arccos, arange
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()
cdef extern from "test_modify.h":

    cdef struct S1:
        float* buffer
        int length

    int modify(S1* s1, char* str)

def modifyPY():
    d = np.zeros((2, 3, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    cdef float[:, :, ::1] d_view = d.astype(np.float32)
    cdef S1 s1 = [&(d_view[0, 0, 0]), np.product(d.shape)]

    cdef char *s = 'jhk'

    modify(&s1, s)

    return d, s
```

** setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy


extensions = [
    Extension("temp",
              sources=["test.pyx", "test_modify.cpp"],
              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
              extra_compile_args=["-O3", '-std=c++11'],
              language="c++")
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)

# to install run, python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

**test.py (run after build)**

```
import temp

d, s = temp.modifyPY()

print(d) # still 0's, should be 10's
print(s) # still "jhk" should be "newstr'
```

Comment: What is `depthBuffer` in test.pyx? It's not defined.

Comment: Your code doesn’t build, please provide [mcve].

Comment: For what it's worth I'd expect changing the array in `S1` to work (except that we don't know `w` and `h`), but not the string.

Comment: I have updated the code with a minimal reproducible example which should build. I used cython 0.29.21 version for the build. Thnx

Comment: And what is the output, when you print d and s?

Comment: It is in the test.py file. This should run after running the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cdef float[:, :, ::1] d_view = d.astype(np.float32)
```

[Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

> By default, `astype` always returns a newly allocated array

i.e. `d_view` is a view of a copy of `d`, not a view of `d`. We therefore do not expect changes made by `d_view` to reflect in `d`.

---

```
int modify(S1* s1, char* str) {
    str = "newstr"; // string modify
```

This is a basic C pointer passing problem. `str` and `s` in Python both point to the same place, but they are *different pointers*. After `str` is reassigned in `str = "newstr"` they now point to different places.

You probably want a pointer-to-a-pointer (`char**`)?

Comment: It worked as expected. Thanks. I didn't know astype return a newly allocated array. Aso, It has been years since I used c++ so forgot most of the concepts. Thanks